# Completely clean-up sd card and create new partition table

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

My friend recently asked me to help him with his sd card. It just stopped working. So I borrowed it and plugged it to my PC. What I got, was basically nothing. No partitions, corrupted partition table. Is there a way to completely clean up everything that is on the SD card and create clean new msdos partition table (I know how to create partitions myself)? I have both Windows (8.1) and Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and I know how to use console well.

Answer (score 1):

Windows you can use diskpart utility .
in Command prompt use diskpart > list disk  > select disk 1,2,3(choose which disk you want to format)  > clean

once clean then you can create partition using  command "create par pri fs=fat32 quick"

in Linux ubuntu you can use disk GUI based tool as well. where you can select disk and format it.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and straight forward way is using the SD Card formatter from "SD Association" that is responsible for designing the SD specifications.

There are versions available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/

Alternatively, you can use the disk partitioning and file system formatting tools that come with your OS (Disk Management, Disk Utility).

In case of issues that are not hardware related, it's often enough to zero fill the first sector of the SD Card using a tool like DD or a disk editor.

If issues persist or whatever you write does not 'stick'. For example you discover writing zeros to the first sector does not overwrite the MBR / boot sector or formatting does not actually wipe existing files then the SD Card may have become read-only.

In many cases this is due to a feature rather than an error: A card's firmware can switch the card to read-only mode in case of errors or the NAND memory having depleted it's write / erase cycles. Since this is done at the firmware level this can not be overcome using end user software.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GParted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) to delete the entire SD Card and for creating partition tables etc.
It is a simple tool and powerful.

Comment: I have GParted. How to delete entire sd card (including partition table)?

Comment: Just click "Device->Create Partition Table" it will warn you when the SD card has already a partition table, you can than select the type of the new partition table e.g., msdos as you mentioned it.